# How to align cards in different rows

Tags: javascript, css, handlebars.js, bulma

I'm trying to do something like this: https://nomadlist.com/

Rows of 3 elements (cards?) Going from top to bottom. Same size, perfectly aligned.

I'm using Handlebars and Bulma CSS, and the card components and doing this:

```
<div class="columns">
    {{#each serverElements}}
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
          {{this.title}}
        </p>
        <a class="card-header-icon">
          <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
      </header>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
          {{this.body}}
          <a>@bulmaio</a>. <a>#css</a> <a>#responsive</a>
          <br>
          <small>this.createdAt</small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <a class="card-footer-item">Save</a>
        <a class="card-footer-item">Edit</a>
        <a class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
      </footer>
    </div>
    </div>

      {{/each}}
  </div>
```

And it partially works. Each of the elements gets its own card. But this prints them all on the same row. And with different sizes.

Comment: I don't see any rows being created in the HTML.

Comment: Please try giving display:inline-block to your card elements

Comment: I don't think there is any magic to the site you referenced. The items are each 33.3% wide and have a fixed-height.

Comment: SO is here to help with markup you wrote but SO is not here to write markup for you. The HTML is not everything we need to see from you.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right, You sould use the `is-multiline` modifier with the right column, if you want 3 in a row, then use `column is-4'.